# Understanding Azure DevOps Billing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-billing

There are 2 parts to this question:

1. The Azure DevOps pricing website is very unclear (to say the least).

If I have subscription A - and I create a DevOps organisation under this subscription, how many FREE accounts do I get (in that Organisation)?

So if I have 2 organisations - would I get 5 + 5 free Basic accounts?

2. Secondly,concerning Azure Stakeholder user - surely this user can be given a PAT to deploy their code to Azure Repos? No?

Or is that only BASIC user privilege?

Answer (score -1):

Every organization has first 5 Basic users free. [Pricing for Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/) .

In Private project, Azure Stakeholder has no access to Azure Repos. In Public project, Azure Stakeholder has full access to Azure Repos. You can refer to [Public versus private feature access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/stakeholder-access?view=azure-devops#public-versus-private-feature-access).

Comment: The question is basically: When I create a new organisation, do I get 5 FREE BASIC USERS PER Organisation??

Comment: @houba `do I get 5 FREE BASIC USERS PER Organisation`  The new organizaton you created will get 5 free basic users.